# How can I download image in collection view and keep the image height in cell with Alamofireimage in Swift?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, alamofire, alamofireimage

I want to download images with **Alamofire** and refresh my collectionView to see the images with the correct height size. Something like the foursquare gallery:

My class is:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  ImageList
//
//  Created by Dasoga on 4/7/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Dasoga. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage


class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate,     UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

@IBOutlet var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!

var images:[UIImage] = []
var imagesURL:[String] = ["http://www.apple.com/mx/ipod/home/images/social/og.jpg?201601060706", "http://images.apple.com/home/images/og.jpg?201604012321","http://www.impactony.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Apple-logo1.jpg","http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4973/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/i/ph/iphone6s/plus/iphone6s-plus-box-gray-2015_GEO_US?wid=478&hei=595&fmt=jpeg&qlt=95&op_sharpen=0&resMode=bicub&op_usm=0.5,0.5,0,0&iccEmbed=0&layer=comp&.v=PS8m10"]
var ImageCache = [String:UIImage]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imagesURL.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    cell.imageViewCell.image = UIImage(named: "placeholderImage")
    cell.imageViewCell.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
    //Download image
    let dishName = imagesURL[indexPath.row]
    if let dishImage = ImageCache[dishName] {
        cell.imageViewCell.image = dishImage
    }
    else {
        let url = imagesURL[indexPath.row]
        Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
            .responseImage { response in
                //debugPrint(response)
                debugPrint(response.result)

                if let image = response.result.value {
                    print("image downloaded: \(image)")

                    // Store the commit date in to our cache
                    self.ImageCache[dishName] = image

                    // Update the cell
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        if let cellToUpdate = self.myCollectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? ImageCollectionViewCell{
                            cellToUpdate.imageViewCell.image = image
                            self.images.append(image)
                        }
                    })

                }else{
                    print("error getting image at cell")
                }
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

}

Example of foursquare:

[image]
[image]

I'm getting this:

[image]

Thanks!!

**Edited:**

I added this line:

```
  self.myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```

After:

```
  // Update the cell
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        if let cellToUpdate = self.myCollectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? ImageCollectionViewCell{
                            cellToUpdate.imageViewCell.image = image
                            self.images.append(image)
                            self.myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
                        }
                    })
```

And call this method:

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize{
    let dishName = imagesURL[indexPath.row]
    if let dishImage = ImageCache[dishName] {
        print("found image")
        return CGSizeMake(dishImage.size.width,dishImage.size.height)
    }else{
        return CGSizeMake(200,200)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to implement the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol, which is used to customize the size of the cells, and use this function:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
          sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize{
    let dishName = imagesURL[indexPath.row]
        if let dishImage = ImageCache[dishName] {
            return CGSizeMake(dishImage.frame.width,dishImage.frame.height)
        }

    }
```

This code will set both width and height of the cell as those of the image, if you want to use a different width you need to change the width in the CGSizeMake object.

Comment: Thanks @Ezechiele I just update my post with my final code, because I'd been implemented the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol and I'd tried implement the function sizeForItemAtIndexPath. You help me to get the image of indexPath.